# Extjs Cell value disappearing in roweditor

Tags: extjs, touch, roweditor

I have created a row editor grid.
Rowediting plugin is also used inorder to update/cancel the values.

On roweditor grid focusleave event is added on a cell.

In the focusleave event there is a calculation to find a value and set on other cell

The code is working fine in normal laptops where the cell value is being set properly.

In touch laptops,before the focusleave event is called the completeedit event of rowediting plugin is calling and the value is not populating on the cell.

My observation is the focusleave event of editor and completeedit event of editing plugin are triggering asynchronously

How to solve this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What happens if you try with the `change` event?

Comment: With change event,the calculation of values in cells is not proper because three fields are interdependent. User should get the calculated values after entering whole cell value.so change event won't work.

Comment: Version of extjs is 6.0.2

Comment: Try setting below configs in start of your application
Ext.supports.Touch = false;
Ext.supports.TouchEvents = false;
Ext.supports.touchScroll = 0;

Comment: If we disable that the entire application wont be tested with touch.